# adding headers to a rspec get

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am a newbie at rspec - there it's said!

I'm trying to pass a jwt token to a get request. 
I have seen several posts saying that the syntax is:

`get :endpoint, params: {}, headers: {}`

So that's what I do:

```
require 'rails_helper'
require "rack/test"
include Rack::Test::Methods

def authenticated_header(user, password)
  response = AuthenticateUser.call(user, password)
  { "Authorization" => response.result }
end

RSpec.describe Api::AlbumsController, type: :controller do
  it "returns albums" do
    get :index, params: {}, headers: authenticated_header("admin", "123")
    puts response.body
  end
end
```

But I get an error:

```
F.....

Failures:

  1) Api::AlbumsController returns albums
     Failure/Error: get "/index", params: {}, headers: authenticated_header("admin", "123")

     ArgumentError:
       unknown keyword: headers
     # ./spec/controllers/photos_controller_spec.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.44102 seconds (files took 8.6 seconds to load)
6 examples, 1 failure
```

what am I doing wrong? 
Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unfortunately, [rspec doesn't allow to set request headers](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1655), so you'll need to workaround it like this:

```
  it "returns albums" do
    request.headers.merge!(authenticated_header("admin", "123"))
    get "/index", params: {}
    puts response.body
  end
```

Answer (score 3):

If you get rid of the `type: :controller` and switch to using the named route `photo_path` instead of `:index` it accepts the `:headers`.

Comment: Helped me, I didn't need to explicitly use the named route helpers though, any valid string URL worked

Comment: In this case, not recognizing params hash.Getting missing required keys: [:id, :thermostat_id]

Answer (score 0):

In rspec-rails 4.0 I had to use a slightly different format to add to the header for my spec:

`request.headers.merge!(HTTP_REFERER: 'http://test.host/home')`